# using update panel in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, updatepanel

Please explain me how to create update panel in ASP.NET MVC4 application. I looked for many blogs... but can not find any useful way.
This is my view
[image]

How I can separate these actions in same view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two panels don't allow the user to switch between one or the other so I assume that you have an "intro" view with the option to either Sign in or Register. Right? In that case there is no real need for client side panel switching using Javascript/Ajax. Your "intro" view can pass a parameter to the controller action defining whether it needs a Sign In or Register view back.

For instance:

```
// RouteConfig.cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "login-register/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Authentication"},
    constraints: new { action = @"(SignIn|Register)" }
);

// AuthenticationController.cs
public ActionResult SignIn() 
{
    ...
    return View(); // Will return the Authentication\SignIn.cshtml view
}

public ActionResult Register()
{
    ...
    return View(); // Will return the Authentication\Register.cshtml view
}
```

Comment: Do you know if this will "suffer" from the postback flicker that made updatepanels popular to begin with?

Answer (score 5):

Update panel does not really exist in ASP.NET MVC. It used to be there in ASP.NET Web form develeopment world before people actually realized it is better to use hand written  jQuery ajax for doing the partial page update.

You may use jQuery ajax methods to post your form data to an action method and do partial page update to the page as needed. You may also consider using Partial view (to return a part of a page) as required.

In your case you can create 2 partial views for Sign in and Register and include those in your  main view, to make your code more reusable.

```
<h1>Login or Register</h1>
<div>
  @Html.Partial("Login")
</div>
<div>
 @Html.Partial("Register")
</div>
```

Comment: I used this idea. Thank you.